# Mark Test As Inconclusive SpecFlow C# With Custom Tag

Tags: c#, specflow

I am using SpecFlow and have recently run under a condition of marking my tests which have raised bugs to be inconclusive.

I have written following code but it is throwing exceptions, Not Sure What I am missing, any assistance would be really appreciated.

```
 if (ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Any(e => e.ContainsIgnoreCase("BUG")))
            {

string tag = ScenarioContext.Current.ScenarioInfo.Tags.Where(e => 
e.ContainsIgnoreCase("BUG")).First();
                string[] bugDetails = tag.Split(':').Last().Split(',');

                if (bugDetails.Count() > 0)
                {
                    Logger.WriteError("There are Active/Related bugs for this 
scenario as below:");
                    foreach (string bugId in bugDetails)
                    {
                        Logger.WriteWarning(
                        string.Format(
                            "<b><a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://tfs:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/TP%20Git/_workitems?id={0}&_a=edit\"></a></b>",
                            bugId));
                    }
                }
                var unitTestRuntimeProvider = ScenarioContext.Current
                    .GetBindingInstance((typeof(IUnitTestRuntimeProvider))) 
as IUnitTestRuntimeProvider;

                if (unitTestRuntimeProvider == null)
                {
                    Logger.WriteError("ScenarioContext was not casted to IUnitTestRuntimeProvider properly.");
                }
                unitTestRuntimeProvider.TestInconclusive("Inconclusived due 
to an active bug for this scenario");
```

Last line is throwing me exception and inner exception is set null.

What , I am trying to do is marking all my tests that has a tag BUG to be inconclusive and I have defined this code at AfterScenario in SpecFlow Framework.

Let me know, if any doubt
Thanks

Comment: Could you please add the exception to your question? Thanks!

Comment: Inner Exception is null

Comment: And the normal exception?